# How do I get tracepath (not traceroute) for cygwin?

Tags: networking, cygwin, traceroute

I need the tracepath utility (not traceroute) on my Windows 7 cygwin. "The main difference between the two is that you need to be a superuser on a Linux computer to use traceroute, whereas tracepath can be run without this credential".

Ideally I would like to get it either as source code that I can compile/build or as something that can be installed locally. How do I get tracepath?

Basically, I need to "trace a packet from my computer to the host" to diagnose a network issue and I do not need any fancy additional functionality.

Comment: I think I found an answer: https://superuser.com/questions/915657/how-to-simulate-traceroute-using-ping

Answer (score 1):

> Basically, I need to "trace a packet from my computer to the host" to diagnose a network issue

But you already have traceroute – it comes as `tracert.exe` with all Windows installations. It can be used without administrator privileges.

```
C:\>tracert -d superuser.com

Tracing route to superuser.com [151.101.1.69]
over a maximum of 30 hops:

  1    <1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  192.168.1.254
  2   123 ms    18 ms    18 ms  78.58.207.254
  3    19 ms    19 ms    18 ms  82.135.179.112
  4  ^C
```

Moreover, the quote about the differences is 1) untrue, as it only applies to ICMP-based tracing while Linux traceroute uses unprivileged UDP-based tracing by default; 2) is about Linux and doesn't even apply to Cygwin.